# Cut a string at max length and specific character

Tags: vbscript

I've got a string that contain value separate by ";". Unfortunately, the program cannot accept more than 4000 char. So I should cut every 4000 if len is bigger than 4000

The problem is I cannot cut a value. I'm lucky if I cut at a ";".

So how to get less that 4000 without cutting a value?

Comment: Post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start from position 4000 and work your way backwards until you find a comma. This code creates a test string but you can set `sValues` to whatever your value is:

```
Dim sValues
Dim iCounter

For iCounter = 1 To 1000
    If sValues <> "" Then sValues = sValues & ","
    sValues = sValues & "value" & iCounter
Next

If Len(sValues) > 4000 Then

    For iCounter = 4000 To 1 Step -1
        If Mid(sValues, iCounter, 1) = "," Then
            ' Last comma before 4000 is found
            sValues = Left(sValues, iCounter - 1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End If

MsgBox Right(sValues, 10)
```

I show the last 10 characters to verify that the string was trimmed properly.

Another approach is to use the [Split function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) and build the string back up until it reaches 4000.

Comment: Good !! The split function should works for what i need. I can split by ";" and count lenght in a loop.